# Sharepoint custom FBA authenticate in Azure AD

Tags: sharepoint-server, forms-authentication, azure, azure-ad, sso

We've configured a custom FBA with Sharepoint 2013 on-prem. The custom FBA is connected with two Microsoft Active Directory and one SQL server to resolve the users.

We are trying to use Azure AD to authenticate users in Sharepoint but we don't whant to create another provider and prompt the Azure login page, we whant to use the custom FBA to make a request with username/password to Azure AD and get a token/user_info to authenticate the user.

1. How can we make a request to Azure AD with username/password and get a token/user info?
2. Is possible to use this Azure AD token and create STS-Token for FBA?
3. FBA and Azure AD Authentication can work together?

Answer (score 0):

To use Azure AD to authenticate users in SharePoint, you will need to configure a new trusted identity provider apart from ASP.NET membership provider.

SAML token-based authentication is a different [authentication type](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/security-for-sharepoint-server/plan-user-authentication#supported-authentication-types-and-methods) from Forms-based authentication. They can work parallelly but not integrated with each other.

References:

[Tutorial: Azure Active Directory single sign-on integration with SharePoint on-premises.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/sharepoint-on-premises-tutorial)

[Using Microsoft Azure Active Directory for SharePoint 2013.](https://simoferr.wordpress.com/2016/07/15/using-microsoft-azure-active-directory-for-sharepoint-2013/)